# XPath: Show information in different DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath

I'm a little noob and I need help...I have this XML document:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

And this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p <div style="color:#0770FF"  id="demo"  ></p>
    <script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(xhttp.responseXML);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", true);
xhttp.send(); 

function showResult(xml) {
    var txt = "";
   path = "/bookstore/book //title | //author | //price  | //price | //year"
 
    if (xml.evaluate) {
        var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var result = nodes.iterateNext();
        while (result) {
            txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            result = nodes.iterateNext();
        } 
   
    } 
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is: How do I show the information in different columns / `DIV`s? For example:

- column-1 title
- column-2 author
- column-3 year....etc

I'm sorry if my question may be a bit stupid, but I cannot find the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, check your favourite HTML reference on how HTML tables look like. Then decide whether you want to statically insert the table in your HTML and only add some rows with Javascript or whether you want to construct the whole HTML table with Javascript. To construct HTML elements with Javascript in the browser you can use the W3C DOM although it seems you prefer string concatenation and assigning the result to innerHTML.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time, i want to statically insert the table in my HTML , I have a very basic level ....If I have 3 div for example, how to select that the author node must be in the div 1, year in div2? ...etc